# What exceptions should I expect from P/Invoke unsafe code?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

In my solution I've written the following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern unsafe bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName,  
 string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData,  
 Boolean* pbCancel,    CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

...

bool result;

unsafe{
  result = CopyFileEx(sourceFile, targetFile, null, IntPtr.Zero,  
                      null /* pointer */, 0);
}

if(!result)
    Win32Exception exc = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); 
// parameter could be omitted according to Win32Exception constructor 
// implementation
```

In the assumption that CopyFileEx was exported with SetLastError = true parameter of DllImport attribute, do I have a chance to get any unhalted exception here?

I'm specifically interested in non-CLR exceptions which are wrapped in RuntimeWrappedException instance. In C++ "throw 1" is a valid construct. So what exceptions should I expect from such P/Invoke calls and where I can obtain such information regarding exceptions (MSDN says nothing regarding exceptions from CopyFileEx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET PInvoke Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555311/net-pinvoke-exception-handling)

Comment: actually I haven't found an irrefragable answer there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a DLL uses the Win32 structured exception handling system, then any exceptions thrown by the DLL will be translated to `OutOfMemoryException`, `AccessViolationException`, `NullReferenceException` (rarely), or `SEHException`.

`RuntimeWrappedException` is only used when *managed* C++ throws a non-`Exception`-derived object. It is not used for unmanaged DLLs. If you had a *managed* C++ DLL that did a `throw 1`, then you could catch `RuntimeWrappedException`.

`SEHException` acts as a catch-all for the unmappable types of SEH exceptions from *unmanaged* DLLs. This would include any C++ class, or the `throw 1` example. AFAIK, there is no way to pull the C++-specific exception info out of `SEHException`, though I'm sure it's hackable if you try hard enough.

Note that there are a few DLLs that do not use the Win32 structured exception handling system. Most notably Cygwin DLLs. In that case, any C++ exception is likely to crash the process or at least your thread. Naturally, all the Windows DLLs (including the one defining `CopyFileEx`) do use Win32 structured exception handling, as do any unmanaged DLLs created by Microsoft's C++ compiler.

Also note that the Win32 API (including `CopyFileEx`) does not normally report errors using Win32 structured exceptions; they report them via `GetLastError`. The only way to get most Win32 functions to throw a Win32 structured exception is to pass it wildly invalid arguments (such as asking it to write into the middle of `ntdll.dll`).

Comment: One of the most comprehensive explanations regarding this topic, especially w.r.t RuntimeWrappedException being only able to wrap managed C++ exceptions. The MSDN wasn't clear on this.